# NSURLUnsupportedURL -1002 on seemingly valid URL

Tags: swift, swift2, nsurl, alamofire

I am querying a search on a website I do not own, using Alamofire.
The code im using worked just fine on other URLs, just not this one. Im getting an unsupported URL response on URLs such as "http://www.180.no/bransje/ADMINCONS-AS/1.htm". I printed the URL and just `curl`d it, that worked fine. Somehow this does not work with Alamofire. Any obvious mistakes im doing?

Code:

```
   //Search 180.no for info page 
                                    let search180Query = "http://www.180.no/bransje/" + (company.name?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-"))! + "/1.htm"

                                    print(search180Query) //http://www.180.no/bransje/PORTRAIT-MILLION-HANDSHAKES-AS/1.htm
                                    Alamofire.request(.GET, search180Query)
                                            .responseData { searchResultPage in
                                            let searchResultPage = Kanna.HTML(html: searchResultPage.data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                                            let searchResultID = searchResultPage!.xpath("//div[@class='found-company-container-grey foundItem'][1]//@id")
//ERROR: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                                            print(searchResultID.text)
                                    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your Alamofire request? I am getting a `statusCode` of 200 for this url using Alamofire.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK Updated question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question. It wasn|t Alamofire-related, it was my HTML-parsing library Kanna who couldnt read UTF8 because the website was coded with Windows1502. Never encountered that before, interesting choice.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add 
`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)` with Url ?. It may solve your problem.

Swift 1.2 `let search180Query = ("http://www.180.no/bransje/" + (company.name?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-"))! + "/1.htm").stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Swift 2.0 `let search180Query = ("http://www.180.no/bransje/" + (company.name?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-"))! + "/1.htm" as NSString).stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`